Should Kadane's algorithm work for subarrays not necessarily contiguous?
I implemented this by reading about Kadane's algorithm for sum of subsequences
def kadane(arr):
    max_current = 0
    globalSum = 0
    for x in range(0, len(arr)):
        max_current = max(arr[x], max_current + arr[x])
        globalSum = max(globalSum, max_current)
    return globalSum

But for
arr4 = [1, 400, 7, -2, 0, 15]
the subarray should be 1+400+7+0+15, without the -2, giving 423 as answer. Moreover when I run I have 421 as answer because it considers the -2.
To solve the issue, the algorithm should have the line changed to
  max_current = max(arr[x], max_current + arr[x], max_current)

Moreover this is not how Kadane's algorithm should work for what I've read.
Any idea where I got lost?

I couldnt understand your desired result. Do you want to find the max sum of subsequences excluding the negative values (for example for arr4 desired result is 423). Then the problem reduces to the sum of the positive elements of an array and solution differs from Kadane's algorithm.

If you remove the "contiguous" condition from the problem definiton, you will get the max sum by adding all positive elements of the source array to a sub-array.

ah ok, so it seems that when we read "subsequences" we are always talking about contiguous ones

Not exactly, for 'subsequence' you just need to keep the order of elements you can pass some of them when creating a subsequence . Here you can find the correct definitions: link. I was also wrong, now it is clear for me too.

In your code if you modify max_current = max(arr[x], max_current + arr[x]) as max_current = max(max_current, max_current + arr[x]) then your algorithm will work for 'subsequences' which are by definition not contiguous but ordered as the source array. This is also same as adding all positive elements together.
